# Biometrics Logon

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm building a Microsoft Access application with a login authentication feature, I wanted to avoid the need for users to enter a login and password each time they need the use the app and then thought of using biometrics . How can I implement the use of a biometric login to a Microsoft Access application.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reliably achieve this and let it actually be secure (no pseudosecurity), is to store your data in an MS SQL server, use trusted connections, and let the users log into Windows with the fingerprint reader. That way you have your fingerprint authentication and your users don't have to enter a password.

Note that any security that doesn't utilize strong encryption and stores the data locally in a file is likely to actually be unsecure. If you want both solid security and per-user authentication, Access as a storage backend just won't do.

Comment: Thanks Erik, 
Could you pls offer some guide on possible implementation method?

Comment: Eh, I'm pretty explicit. Move your data to a Microsoft SQL server, use that as a backend for your Access database, and use Access as front-end.  Grant the appropriate users access to the database. Then link the tables from the SQL server database in Access using trusted connections. Which step are you having issues with?

Comment: Thanks for the insight,
If I have any other concern, I'll get back to you.
God bless!

Answer (score 0):

Well, Access can read bar codes, but I don't think it can read any kinds of biometrics, unless you are talking about a fingerprint scan, and then perhaps Access could handle it.

I think you should just save your time, rather than messing around with something like this.  All MS apps are notoriously easy to break into, no matter what kind of 'security' features you have implemented.  What is the old saying...you spend 95% of your time keeping out 5% of the hackers.

You can view the link below for some ideas of how to setup standard security for Access.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Encrypt-a-database-by-using-a-database-password-fe1cc5fe-f9a5-4784-b090-fdb2673457ab

Comment: Many thanks for your comment, I'm actually considering a fingerprint scanner and what I intend to achieve is a sort of passwordless login for the app for easier access by the end user.